# Discrete Laplace operator (on graphs) - why are its units not the same as the continuous version of the Laplace operator?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

**From Wikipedia:**

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a graph with vertices $\scriptstyle V$ and edges $\scriptstyle E$. Let $\phi\colon V\to R$ be a function of the vertices taking values in a ring. Then, the discrete Laplacian $\Delta$ acting on $\phi$ is defined by:

$(\Delta \phi)(v)=\sum_{w:\,d(w,v)=1}\left[\phi(w)-\phi(v)\right]$,

where $d(w,v)$ is the graph distance between vertices $w$ and $v$. Thus, this sum is over the nearest neighbors of the vertex $v$.

---

**The question:**

I am going to do some handwavy dimensional analysis. Let the function $\phi$ have units $[F]$. Let $x$, the coordinate over which the Laplacian is taken have units $[L]$. Then, the Laplacian of $\phi$

$\Delta \phi =  \frac {\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2}$,

has units $[F]/[L^2]$. However, the discrete version of the Laplacian, defined on the vertices of a graph seems to have units $[F]$ (see above -- all I am doing is taking the sum of differences, so my units are simply the same as the units of $\phi$).

Why are the units of the discrete version of the Laplacian not the same as the units of the continuous version? What mistake am I making in my "dimensional analysis"?

Comment: The basic idea is roughly that the discrete Laplacian assumes that all edges have unit length.

Comment: I know nothing about this, but does the fact that you are summing over $w$ such that $d(v,w)=1$ matter? I suppose you could view the summands as $\frac{\phi(w) - \phi(v)}{d(v,w)^2}$.

Comment: @Rahul Similar to what Phillip suggested in the comment below you?

Comment: Yeah. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Rahul Awesome! By any chance, do you know of a resource that shows  that clearly? Its making sense to me right now, but I need a more trustworthy source to cite than my intuition.